# Defining a main_menu function to be called from other methods within a class in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, class

I have a class with several methods to assign attributes from user input, and three methods that will add, delete, or update a nested dictionary with the input.
I would like to add a main_menu function so that the user can access the add, delete, and update methods and then choose to either continue adding/deleting/updating the dictionary, or go back to the main menu.

When I tried to make a main_menu function, I receive NameError: name 'command' is not defined. The program will loop through as expected if the main_menu is not a function, but once I tried to turn it into a function, I get the error. I've tried different levels of indentation, but I'm new to Python and don't know what else to try.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.z = 0

    def get_x(self):
        #code to get x from user input
    def get_y(self):
        #code to get y from user
    def get_z(self):
        #code to get z from user

    def add_info(self):
        store_info = {}
        id = 0
        while command = '1':
            new_info = {}
            new_id = len(store_info) + 1
            store_info[new_id] = new_info

            x = h.get_x()
            new_info['x'] = x
            y = h.get_y()
            new_info['y'] = y
            z = h.get_z()
            new_info['z'] = z

            print('Your info has been updated.\n', store_info)
            choice = input('To add more info, type 1. To return to the main menu, type 2')
            if choice == '1':
                continue
            elif choice == '2':
                 main_menu()
            else:
                print('The End')
                break

    def delete_info(self):
        #code to delete, with an option at the end to return to main_menu

    def update_info(self):
        #code to update, with option for main_menu

def main_menu():
    main_menu_option = """Type 1 to add.
Type 2 to delete.
Type 3 to update.
Type any other key to quit.\n"""

    h = MyClass()
    command = input(main_menu_option)
    if command == '1':
        h.add_info()
    elif command == '2':
        h.delete_info()
    elif command == '3':
        h.update_info()
    else:
        print('Good bye.')

main_menu()
```

When I run the program, I get the main menu and type 1, but then receive the NameError for command.
Before I tried to make the main_menu a function, I could access the add method to add info to the nested dictionary.

Comment: Can you please include the stack trace in your question? It helps us to understand the issue better.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. Is that the same as the traceback?

Comment: No worries, it is the same as a traceback. No need to worry about it now though, I've added an answer to your problem :)

Comment: I do want to be better at posting questions, so I need to include more than the NameError? Something like "In add_info while command == '1': NameError: name 'command' is not defined.

Comment: Yeah, at least a couple lines of the traceback would be good. We would mainly be looking for the error text that you just described, plus the line number and the calls that it went through (each line of the traceback)

Comment: Gotcha, I will keep that in mind for future questions. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python methods/functions only have access to variable in their scope or parent scopes. For example:

```py
command = 1  # A

def foo():
    print(command)

def bar():
    command = 2  # B
    print(command)

foo()
bar()
print(command)
```

prints out `1` and then `2` and then `1`. This works because when we call `foo`, python looks at the local variables and realises there is no `command` variable there so it looks at the scope above and sees the `command` variable at label A. Then when we call `bar()` we add a variable called `command` (label B) to the local variables of `bar` and then print that, notice that python doesn't look at the global variables here so it prints `2` without changing the initial `command` variable (label A) as we can see when we finally `print(command)` at the end of the script.

It is because of this that your program is failing, your `add_info` method is trying to access a variable called `command` however none exists in its local variable or its global scope. The fix for this would be to add `command` to the `add_info` local variables by passing it as an argument to the method from `main_menu`.

```py
# in main_menu
if command == '1':
    h.add_info(command)

# in add_info
def add_info(self, command):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been confused about the arguments and completely overlooked that command would be considered an argument in this case. I appreciate your help!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!